# Restore password for FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to restore or reset user password when his status is `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. This situation happened when user try to restore password using "forgot password" feature and he lost email with temporary password. Now he can't do anything because he don't remember password and he can't reset password again

This code handle forgot password

```
return CognitoIdentitySP.forgotPassword(params, (err, resp) => {
  if (err) { ... }
  ...
})
```

And I receive error (in case of `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD` status)

`NotAuthorizedException: User password cannot be reset in the current state.`

Is there any way to reset password in such state?

Answer (score 27):

You can use aws-cli to do it. Here is a sample command, replace `POOL_ID` and `EMAIL_ADDRESS` accordingly:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-create-user --user-pool-id <POOL_ID> --username <EMAIL_ADDRESS> --message-action RESEND --profile <AWS_PROFILE>
```

Comment: Also, consider using `--desired-delivery-mediums EMAIL SMS` if you want the invitation to be sent again using both mediums. Otherwise, it defaults to `SMS`. https://arc.net/l/quote/ilgfdkrj

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the admin-set-user-password command in this situation of the temporary password being lost or expired:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-set-user-password --user-pool-id <POOL_ID> --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --no-permanent
```

This will set a new temporary password of whatever you set the password to be but importantly will force the user to set a new password as soon as they log in, so security is maintained.

You will need to communicate this to the user but we found this extremely useful when your company's security policies prevent you from being able to run the create user command.

Comment: This is a great solution if the SMS configuration is missing!

Comment: My issue was that I migrated my userpool and every user had the status `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`, which prevented them from resetting their password. What finally solved it, was using this command with `--permanent` to set the password to a new value, after which users are able to reset their passwords and log in as normal.

Answer (score 6):

You can call admin create user again with the MessageAction set to RESEND in which case Cognito will resend the invitation message to a user that already exists and reset the expiration limit on the user's account. Set to "SUPPRESS" to suppress sending the message. Only one value can be specified.

Comment: this works really well and regenerate a new temporary password! If it was my question, I would put this one as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a user from the admin or with the admin sdk from the frontend you have to use the authentication flow "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" previously you should have configured it in the app client:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/switch-auth/q/platform/js/